# For Each Loop in Thymeleaf not retunring results

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've used this method to filter through a list of objects before, so I have no clue why this one isn't working. There are three results that should be showing up in this table, instead I get No results found. In the controller function, if I debug it, I see it is registering the contactList... so not sure why it's not populating in the table. I keep getting this not binded error: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contactList[0]' available as request attribute. I'm not sure how to go about binding it.

Here is the table that isn't populating. The whole HTML page runs through CarrierAppointment as the object.

```html
<table class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-show-toggle="true" data-classes="table-no-bordered" data-striped="true" data-search="true"  data-show-columns="true" >
    <thead>
    <th>Contact Type</th>
    <th>Contact Name</th>
    <th>Contact's Email</th>
    <th>Contact's Phone</th>
    <th th:if="${role.isCarrierAdmin}" class="text-right"><button type="submit" name="addCommercialContact" class="btn btn-default" ><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="contact,stat : *{contactList}">
        <td> <select class="form-control" th:field="*{contactList[__${stat.index}__].contactType}">
            <option value="Account Manager">Account Manager</option>
            <option value="Marketing Manager">Marketing Manager</option>
            <option value="Underwriter">Underwriter</option>
        </select></td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{contactList[__${stat.index}__].contactName}"/></td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{contactList[__${stat.index}__].contactEmail}"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{contactList[__${stat.index}__].contactPhone}"/></td>
        <td> <input type="hidden" class="form-control" th:field="*{contactList[__${stat.index}__].contactTable}" th:value="Commercial Lines"/></td>
        <td class="text-right" th:if="${role.isCarrierAdmin}"> <button type="submit" name="removeContact" th:value="${stat.index}" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the controller function:

```
       @RequestMapping(value="/carrierAppointment/details/{id}")
public String viewDetails(Model model,@PathVariable("id")CarrierAppointment carrierAppointment){
    String username= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    Role role=roleRepository.findByUsernameContainingIgnoreCaseAndActive(username,true);
    Document newDoc=new Document();

    List<CarrierContact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    CarrierContact contact = new CarrierContact();
    contactList.add(contact);

    model.addAttribute("contact",contact);
    model.addAttribute("role",role);
    model.addAttribute("newDocument",newDoc);
    model.addAttribute("docs",documentRepository.findByCarrierAppointment(carrierAppointment));
    model.addAttribute("carrier",carrierAppointment);
    model.addAttribute("contactList",contactList);
    return "carrierAppointments/carrierDetails";
}
```

Contact Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CarrierContact")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="contactId")
    private Long id;
    private String contactType;
    private String contactName;
    private String contactEmail;
    private String contactPhone;
    private Long carrier;
    private String contactTable;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContactType() {
        return contactType;
    }

    public void setContactType(String contactType) {
        this.contactType = contactType;
    }

    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public String getContactEmail() {
        return contactEmail;
    }

    public void setContactEmail(String contactEmail) {
        this.contactEmail = contactEmail;
    }

    public String getContactPhone() {
        return contactPhone;
    }

    public void setContactPhone(String contactPhone) {
        this.contactPhone = contactPhone;
    }

//    public CarrierAppointment getCarrier() {
//        return carrier;
//    }
//
//    public void setCarrier(CarrierAppointment carrier) {
//        this.carrier = carrier;
//    }
//
    public Long getCarrier() {
        return carrier;
    }

    public void setCarrier(Long carrier) {
        this.carrier = carrier;
    }

    public String getContactTable() {
        return contactTable;
    }
```

Carrier Appointment Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CarrierAppointment")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class CarrierAppointment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CarrierAppointmentId")
    private Long id;
    private String parentCompanyCarrier;
    private String writingCompany;
    private String masterAgencyCode;
    private String serviceCenterCode;
    private String affiliateSubcode;
    private String clMarketingContact;
    private String plMarketingContact;
    private String clUnderwriterContact;
    private String plUnderwriterContact;
    private String plAccountManager;
    private String clAccountManager;
    private String supportDesk;
    private String licensingDept;
    private String custServiceDept;
    private String loginPasswordRequirements;
    private String quotingWebsite;
    private String states;
    private String appetite;
    private String affiliateUseOfLogo;
    private String premiumVolumeRequirementForAffiliateSubcode;
    private String notes;
    private String knownForPersonal;
    private String knownForCommercial;
    private String linesOfBusiness;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;
    private Boolean carrierDownloads;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "carrier")
    private List<Contact> contactList= new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Contact> getContactList() {
        return contactList;
    }

    public void setContactList(List<Contact> contactList) {
        this.contactList = contactList;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getParentCompanyCarrier() {
        return parentCompanyCarrier;
    }

    public void setParentCompanyCarrier(String parentCompanyCarrier) {
        this.parentCompanyCarrier = parentCompanyCarrier;
    }
```

Comment: where is `contactList` on controller? Also please get rid of code that are not necessary in the context of question as it is hard to grasp what exactly you are trying to ask.

Comment: @want2learn contactList is the array list in the carrier appointment controller. That is what should be iterated over to pull out the info of each contact.

Comment: @Stacie In order to use `contactList` in thymeleaf page you will have have to make a model object in controller class. Like `model.addAttribute("newDocument",newDoc);` you will have to do the same thing like `model.addAttribute("contactList", getlist from method);` . In controller you didn't do that, that's why you are getting null.

Comment: @AvijitBarua that doesn't work either. They way it is set up, there is a list in the Carrier appointment model, so I can access the contacts through the carrier appointment. So I can see the info I am trying to grab just by having model.addAttribute("carrier", carrierAppointment); If I also add in model.addAttribute("contactList", carrierAppointment.getContactList); when I debug, I still see the list but it's not being displayed on the view.

Comment: @Stacie Oh man, You don't understand the problem. You assigning new objet in list by `CarrierContact contact = new CarrierContact();
contactList.add(contact);`
And you expecting value to show in database? Post your repository class where you wrote code to get `CarrierContact` list

Comment: @AvijitBarua I am pulling the contactList from the carrierAppointment model, not from the carrierContact model, as they are joined table in the SQL database. If I do it the way you're suggesting I need to add a repository.

Comment: Got it to work by adding carrier to the field, to clarify where contactList was coming from.     th:field="*{carrier.contactList[__${stat.index}__].contactName}"